# Using variable of another class

Tags: c++, class, vector, nested, coordinates

I want to make some sort of Hirarchy out of classes.

**Example:**

```
object.position.x
```

I want to be able to reuse the Vector3 class for velocity and other things as well, thats why i want to keep it as a class.
I tried it that way.

```
#include"Vector3.h"

class object{
   public:
       Vector3 position;
       Vector3 velocity;
}

-------------------------------------

class Vector3{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work so well as I expected.

When i go for `go.position.x = 0` codeblocks want me to use `->`.

```
request for member 'x' in 'go.GameObject::position', which is of pointer type 'Vector3*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
```

but when i use them like that: `go.position -> x = 0`, the program crashes.
Can someone tell me what the "right" or a better approach of doing this is?

Comment: Please provide the real code, [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the best. The compiler message says `position` is `Vector3*`, while in your code it is `Vector3`.

Comment: Ok i pasted the real code in the answer. Iam sorry i didN#t provide the real code. I was trying to get only the relevant parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you pasted is incomplete and the error you got seems to be coming from different version of the code. Here is the example of using Your classes with and without pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vector3{
    public:
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
};

class Object {
   public:
       Vector3 position;
       Vector3 velocity;
};

class ObjectPointer {
   public:
       Vector3 *positionPtr;
       Vector3 *velocityPtr;

       ObjectPointer()
         : positionPtr(new Vector3()),
         velocityPtr(new Vector3())
       {
       }
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Object obj;
    obj.position.x = 1;
    obj.position.y = 2;
    obj.position.z = 3;
    obj.velocity.x = 11;
    obj.velocity.y = 12;
    obj.velocity.z = 13;

    std::cout << "Object Position (" << obj.position.x
        << ", " << obj.position.y
        << ", " << obj.position.z << ")" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Object Velocity  (" << obj.velocity.x
        << ", " << obj.velocity.y
        << ", " << obj.velocity.z << ")" << std::endl;

    ObjectPointer *objPtr = new ObjectPointer();
    objPtr->positionPtr->x = 5;
    objPtr->positionPtr->y = 6;
    objPtr->positionPtr->z = 7;
    objPtr->velocityPtr->x = 15;
    objPtr->velocityPtr->y = 16;
    objPtr->velocityPtr->z = 17;

    std::cout << "ObjectPointer Position (" << objPtr->positionPtr->x
        << ", " << objPtr->positionPtr->y
        << ", " << objPtr->positionPtr->z << ")" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ObjectPointer Velocity  (" << objPtr->velocityPtr->x
        << ", " << objPtr->velocityPtr->y
        << ", " << objPtr->velocityPtr->z << ")" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like my code got mixed up a little trough trys to fix the errors. It was the  Vector3 * position; Vector3 * velocity; in my code. I didn't need the * operator. But can you tell me what i would need the pointer for? I mean for me it just looks more complicated.

Comment: You do not need to use pointers for Vector3 within the Object. The example I gave you is for your reference. Pointers are more useful in special situations like polymorphism. You should use smart pointers like std::shared_ptr or std::auto_ptr to hold the reference and std::make_shared to create them instead of using "new" operator.

Answer (score 0):

Since members of a class are private by default you cant access them like position.x . You need to write getter and setter for them , else make it struct like .

```
structVector3{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```